# trying to run while loop until element is visible then click that element

Tags: python, loops, selenium, while-loop

I need to get this while loop to continue once element is visible, then click on that element.

tried using expected conditions, but I am a noob so I may be doing something wrong.

```py
# wait until apply clickable
apply = wait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > associate > div > adjust-schedule > div > list-adjustments > div > basecard > div:nth-child(3) > div > fieldset > div > table.table.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6) > button")))

while True:
     try:
         apply = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > associate > div > adjust-schedule > div > list-adjustments > div > basecard > div:nth-child(3) > div > fieldset > div > table.table.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6) > button")
         apply.click()
     except:
         ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
         clckfilter = wait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException)\
             .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/associate/div/adjust-schedule/div/list-adjustments/div/basecard/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/table[1]/thead/tr/th[4]/button")))
         clckfilter.click()
         apply.click()
         driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > associate > div > adjust-schedule > div > list-adjustments > div > basecard > div:nth-child(3) > div > fieldset > div > table.table.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6) > div > button.btn.btn-primary").click()
     # if: EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > associate > div > adjust-schedule > div > list-adjustments > div > basecard > div:nth-child(3) > div > fieldset > div > table.table.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6) > button"): continue
```

If I remove the apply.click and following line, the program will loop like I need, but I can't figure out how to get it to loop until the apply button is visible. (It becomes visible once my work posts a shift)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def click():
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 15)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(“selector”))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(“selector”).click()
except:
    Click()
```

In the above code I have created a separate method for clicking on that element in "try" i have write the code for clicking on that element and if the element not visible than in except section the same method call again until the element visible.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I am struggling to try and integrate the code you wrote. would I replace what I have with this? or add it? So far adding it, I am not able to get the output I need.